# Change .htaccess so it doesn't ignore tilde (~)

Tags: php, web-services, .htaccess, slim

I'm using Slim Framework to create web services. The URL to access them is the following: `.../~ondeequemvaiver/webservices/services/eventos/generos`, but it returns a 404 page not found:

> The requested URL /home/ondeequemvaiver/public_html/webservices/services/index.php was not found on this server.

because the tilde isn't in the URL.

My `.htaccess` is this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

How can I change the `.htaccess` so it doesn't ignore the tilde (~)?

Comment: It is not ignoring `~` but it is translating `~ondeequemvaiver` to `/home/ondeequemvaiver/public_html`

Comment: ok, but it's possible to add some rule in my htaccess, for not translating ~ondeequemvaiver?

Comment: No that cannot be disabled from htaccess. That setting is in Apache config